# get_post_meta not working on category.php

Tags: categories, images, attachments, post-meta

I'm referencing an attached image in my `header.php` page which is displayed as a full screen background on my posts:

```
global $wp_query;
$page_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
$background_image = get_post_meta( $page_id, 'mb_background_image', true );
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $background_image, 'full' );
```

This works fine on single posts, but doesn't work when displaying just one post per page in `category.php`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$page_id variable` wasn't defined in `category.php` so I changed as seen below:

```
$background_image = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mb_background_image', true );
```